# How specify object in datagrid binding

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, silverlight, xaml

How can I specify object in DataGrid binding?
My datagrid have `ItemsSource="{Binding Source=TripsCollection}"` and `AutoGenerateColumns="False"`, and Columns set as:

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
     <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Binding="{Binding TripID}" IsReadOnly="True"></DataGridTextColumn>
     ...
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

But have errors:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'TripID'
>   property not found on 'object' ''Char' (HashCode=7209070)'.
>   BindingExpression:Path=TripID; DataItem='Char' (HashCode=7209070);
>   target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text'
>   (type 'String').

How can I set object to Trip object?

DataContext class:

```
private ObservableCollection<Trip> _tripsCollection;
    public ObservableCollection<Trip> TripsCollection
    {
        get { return _tripsCollection; }
        set { _tripsCollection = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("TripsCollection"); }
    }
```

Trip class:

```
[Table(Name="Trips")]
public class Trip
{
    private uint _tripID;
    private string _start;
    private string _end;
    private DateTime _date;
    private double _length;
    private string _note;
    private uint _carID = 0;
    private EntityRef<Car> _Car;

    ..and properties for this fields..
}
```

Setting up DataContext

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    string connString = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS; Integrated security=SSPI; Connect Timeout=30"; // User Instance=True";
    conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
    conn.Open();

    LogBookViewModel lbvm = new LogBookViewModel(conn);
    DataContext = lbvm;
}
```

Comment: Can we see the class that your DataContext points to?

Comment: Sure, but I add only interesting part...

Comment: Show us where you assign DataContext.

Comment: In MainWindow contructor via DataContext = lbvm; // lbvm = LogBookViewModel class. It's too late for settings up datacontext?

Comment: This place in constructor is absolutely alright.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must change binding in ItemsSource, from this:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Source=TripsCollection}"
```

to this:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding TripsCollection}"
```

If you will have problem with binding in the future try use [snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/).